# getting errors in writing up the game in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created a game after watching few videos for windows platform,but now I want the same for android then it is giving errors,those i am unble to resolve,please help me what to do to remove those errors as i am new to unity concepts are not that much clear to me. errors i am gettings are:

> ```
> 1. Assets/scriptPlayer.js(37,16): BCE0044: expecting ), found 'touch'.
> 2.Assets/scriptPlayer.js(39,38): BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).
> 3.Assets/scriptPlayer.js(22,6): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'useKeyboard'.
> 4.Assets/scriptPlayer.js(24,3): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'dir'
> ```

```
function Update () 
{
    if (!useKeyboard) 
    { 
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;
        dir.y = Input.acceleration.y ;

        transH = dir.x * (playerspeedhor + 10.0f) * Time.deltaTime; 
        transV = dir.y * (playerspeedvar+ 10.0f) * Time.deltaTime; 
    }  else 
    { 
        transH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerspeedhor* Time.deltaTime; 
        transV = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerspeedvar * Time.deltaTime; 
    }

    transform.Translate(transH,transV,0); 
    transform.position.x=Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x,-4,4);
    transform.position.y=Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y,-4,4);

    if (SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer) 
    { 
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        { 
            if (Input.touchCount == 1 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            { 
                touched = true; 
                break; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you switched to android platform in build setting before running for Android

Comment: yes i did..,but device works on touch only.,that why i update my code according to device and m getting above mention errors

Comment: It works for **Touch** because on device you have the code for same in your script,you need to recheck your touch code block as it causing error, now as per your errors, I would suggest you open your script in MonoDevelope-Unity Editor (simply double click on file) and press **Command+B** (For MAC) to build. you will get exact hint in your code where is the problem, This is how I works on Unity for iOS, Android & Window with JS & C# scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing programming languages here. C# and UnityScript (or JavaScript, which it isn't really, but let's not get off track).

Your `foreach` should be

```
for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches)
```

instead.

Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html), I'm assuming you retrieved your code from there. If so, always make sure you have the language behind "Scripting Reference using" set to the correct language. And even if so, don't count on it being correct. Too many examples are only available in a single language, resulting in copy-paste problems far too often.